# On Toolbar what does app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" do?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

I'm modifying an old app I have and I noticed my toolbar has `app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"` but I'm not totally sure what it affects? I've changed the colors on the style that is defined with that name and I didn't see any changes on the screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PopupOverlay theme is applied to the overflow menu popup.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html